# Get the content size of view React Native outputs?

Tags: react-native

React Native provides a view class called `RCTRootView`. You specify the frame in which the RootView should render things, and it goes ahead and does it.

In my use-case though, the size of the content view is dynamic, and depends on the data being passed into React Native. This size is important because I'm going to put the React Native view into e.g. a self-sizing cell.

How is this done?

Comment: Is this for embedding RN in another app? If not, what's your use case?

Comment: @ColinRamsay what do you mean 'another' app? I just want the contents of a CollectionViewCell to be a RN view, essentially.

I need to know the size of the contents so that I can, say, adjust the auto-layout constraints for the CollectionViewCell so that it's laid out automatically. However, it's not clear how you can get RN's content's height after rendering.

Comment: Alternatively, I want to add the `RCTRootView` into a native `UIScrollView`, which I've preconfigured with some special behaviour, for instance. The scrollview needs to know the size of the contents.

Comment: @fatuhoku did you figure this out?

Comment: @rhodesy22 Yes I did! Set up a callback on the view's `onLayout` prop, which gets called with (x,y,width,height).  I then call a native module method which emits this rectangle information as a notification. And in the right place in the viewController, I observe for this notification, setting the scrollView's contentSize appropriately. Seems to work well.

Answer (score 2):

@fatuhoku I came to the same conclusion after some digging around. For anyone else who's looking to do this, here's an example.

- Declare your bridge to native code where we'll be sending the content
  size (where depends on preference, I create the instance outside of
  any class/function at the top of the file).
- Call a method in the onLayout property of a JSX component.
- In the onLayout method being called, send the content size data to the bridge.
- Use the content size in the native ObjC or Swift code as you need.

```
// MyReactComponent.jsx (ES6)
```

`// Modules
var React = require('react-native');
var { View } = React;

// Bridge
var ReactBridge = require('NativeModules').ReactBridge;

// Type Definitions
type LayoutEvent = {
  nativeEvent: {
    layout: {
      x: number;
      y: number;
      width: number;
      height: number;
    };
  };
};

// React Component
class MyReactComponent extends React.Component {

  onViewLayout(e: LayoutEvent) {
    ReactBridge.setLayout(e.nativeEvent.layout);
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <View onLayout={ this.onViewLayout }>
        <ChildComponentExample />
      </View>
    );
  }
}`

Then in ObjC you use the RCT_EXPORT_METHOD as described in [React Native's documentation](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/nativemodulesios.html) to create the "ReactBridge" and handle the the data sent on the "setLayout" method. The data will be an NSDictionary in this case but you could just as easily send only the layout height and you'd then get a CGFloat.